# Run another another setup during instllation

Tags: setup-deployment

I am using Visual Studio Setup and Deployment.  I have built a setup project, I want to run another setup file during installation of my main setup. Please advise how to to it.

Thanks

Comment: 10+ points from Azzy just to finish your century :)